# Update rows with multiple values from other table - BigQuery

Tags: sql-update, google-bigquery

I have two tables in `Bigquery` **Table A** and **Table B**.

Table A has two columns - **name**(String) & **value**(Float). The Name columns is can contain **null** values.

Table B has 3 columns - **start_value**(Float), **end_value**(FLoat) and **name**(String). These 3 columns won't be empty at any cost.

My aim is to **update** Table A for the rows having **name** as null. The logic is basically identify the value for which **name** is null and then find the corresponding row in Table B where

```
a.value >= b.start_value and a.value <= b.end_value
```

In this way, I have to update all the rows in Table A in a single query. How can I achieve this?

Note: No two rows in Table A will be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.tableA` a 
SET a.name = b.name
FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b
WHERE a.name IS NULL
AND value BETWEEN start_value AND end_value
```

Comment: so, you do not have rows in tableA that match your criteria

Comment: i have the rows!! when i take count of the rows where it is null, i am getting some value

Comment: but this is not the ONLY criteria - right? you should have value stuff too

Comment: always **value** contains non-null value unlike **name**

Comment: correct. and there should be row in tableB where `value BETWEEN start_value AND end_value`

Comment: yes, that's right, in the table B there won't be any null values

Comment: i think - you are not following me :o( .  show one row in table A that yo think should be updated and respective row from tableB so we can troubleshoot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181926/discussion-between-devios-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a code that works perfectly on my end:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.tableA` a
SET a.name = (
      SELECT b.name
      FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b
      WHERE value BETWEEN start_value AND end_value)
WHERE a.name IS NULL
```